# Is there an equivalent to jQuery's .unwrap() for Dojo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have a scenario similar to this:

```
<div class="DivParent">
   <div class="Child1"></div>
   <div class="Child2"></div>
   <div class="Child3"></div>
</div>
```

I want an HTMLObject of Child1, Child2, and Child3 w/o the DivParent parent.

If I was using jQuery I could say:

```
var HTMLObjectIWant = $('.Parent > div').unwrap();
```

But I'm not ... I'm using Dojo and I would love to see this done in Dojo.  Also- the order (Child1, Child2, Child3 is very important).

Thanks in advance.

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dojo.unwrap = dojo.unwrap || function(/* node ID or node */ n) {
    var node = dojo.byId(n).parentNode;
    dojo.query(' > *', node).forEach(function(childNode) {
        dojo.place(childNode, node, 'before');
    });

    dojo.destroy(node);
}
```

You'll probably want to neaten this up, for example currently it throw an error if n is undefined.

Comment: That's a winner!  Thanks!- I'm using it now.